# how to retrieve an object inside a vector in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference

I'm a C++ noob programmer... (I usually use Java) and now I've got some problems with pointers, references and vectors...

I need to extract an `Object` from `vector<Object> objects` and for simplicity i would like to store *his reference* in another object cause I need to edit some parameters inside of it many times

this is the code i've written so far:

```
Object myObject = getMyObject(id, objects);
```

and `getMyObject` simply implements a `for` cycle which finds the right `object` with the right `id` and it returns it with `return objects[i]`

but if I understood right, this method duplicates the objects! so, in `myObject` there's a completely different `Object`, is it right?

How should I do??

Thank you very much!

Comment: But you say "I would like to store it in another object"... Then you have a copy, right? You can't have an object stored in an array, and the very same object also stored somewhere else.

Comment: If you know you have "problems" with pointers, references, perhaps would it be a good idea to "fix these problems" first for your future developments. These notions may also be useful in other languages (like Java), to understand how things works.

Comment: yes... you're right, I mean I want access to that exact object

Comment: @ereOn i'm in a hurry and I need this very quickly, and an example is the best way for me to learn!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. What you should do is have the get function return a reference:

```
Object & getMyObject(int id, std::vector<Object> & objects)
{
    // ... find ...
    return objects[i];
}
```

Then bind this to another reference in your user code:

```
Object & theobject = getMyObject(12, all_objects);
```

Now you modify the contained element directly via the reference `theobject`.

If you don't want/need to modify the object, just inspect them, you should make the reference (as well as the container) `const`:

```
Object const & getMyObject(int id, std::vector<Object> const & objects);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to use either a pointer or a reference, otherwise the line you showed will call the copy constructor of `Object`.

You can make `getMyObject` return `Object*`, and then you've got a pointer to the object and you can assign it to another `Object*`.

Alternatively, define `myObject` as a reference: `Object& myObject`.

Anyway you must make sure the object you're returning is allocated dynamically and not as a local variable in `getMyObject()`, because otherwise you'll get an access violation.

You also must make sure the object is freed in order to prevent a memory leak.

Comment: @Janky: This is a great place to quickly clear your doubts: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/references.html. You should read all of it if you have the time.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to duplicate the object, then you need a reference or pointer to it.  The problem with this is that the reference or pointer can easily become invalid.  If you don't want that to happen, then you should store pointers in your vector.  Specifically for this case, you would most likely want shared_ptr.

```
std::shared_ptr<Object> getMyObject(foo id,
    const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>> & objects)
{
    // ... find object
    ...
    return objects[i];
}
...
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>> objects;
objects.emplace_back(new Object(parameters));
...
std::shared_ptr<Object> x = getMyObject(id, objects);
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that STL always copies unless specified otherwise. However, vector's at() as well as operator[] both return a reference.

You need

```
Object& myObject = objects.at(id);
```

if you want to change the objects which is inside the collection.

```
Object myObject = objects.at(id);
```

will give you a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Store pointers to the original objects in the container instead.

```
Object* obj1 = new Object();
Object* obj2 = new Object();

vector<Object*> myVector;
myVector.push_back(obj1);
myVector.push_back(obj2);

Object* tmpObj = myVector.at(0);
```